# I get an error trying to query my database in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the SqlDataReader to work, but i get this error:

> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialised.

I tried to initialize it with `SqlDataReader = new SqlDataReader();`
but that throws me another error.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BETSY\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ShoppingList2, con");
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"SELECT * FROM ShoppingList2, con"

Should be
`"SELECT * FROM ShoppingList2", con`

Comment: I couldnt because of the timer.. you have to wait 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BETSY\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        // sql setup stuff here
        using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // read data here
        }
    }
}
```